# How to change lambda of loess function in geom_smooth?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, loess

I have been reading this article on [how loess is defined](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0261379499000281). I'm trying to change the alpha and lambda parameters in the `geom_smooth` function of the `tidyverse`. Using a local dataset in R, I have plotted a normal loess using this default code:

```
#### Load Library ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Plot Default Loess ####
ggplot(iris,
       aes(x=Sepal.Width,
           y=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth()
```

Which gives this typical loess plot:

[image]

However, I'm not entirely sure how to modify the alpha and lambda. I'm assuming so far that the `span` argument in `geom_smooth` is what alters alpha, as seen below:

```
#### Change Alpha ####
ggplot(iris,
       aes(x=Sepal.Width,
           y=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(span = .35)
```

[image]

From the description of alpha in the article, this seems to be correct. As alpha is lowered, fitting the line to more noise is normal. However, I didn't seem to see if lambda could be modified in the same fashion. Is there a way to change this in `ggplot`, or does one have to find some other manual way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `geom_smooth` function calls the `stats::loess` [function](https://rdrr.io/r/stats/loess.html)  which has the paramters `span` (alpha), and `degree` (lambda), which defaults to 2, but can be changed with the `method.args` parameter:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = loess, method.args = list(degree = 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

To start with, a side note: the linked paper is behind a paywall and anyone without access can't figure out what α and λ mean. Keep in mind that statistical terms are not necessarily universal and that's especially true for parameter names. Here is instead the Wikipedia page about [LOESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression).

It's often helpful to be more explicit with argument specification. Here I use the `method` and `method.args` arguments to choose "loess" as the smoother and pass along two smoothing parameters:

- `span`: the proportion of observations to be used in each local regression, ie, the size of the neighborhood. This parameter is called α in the paper.
- `degree`: the degree of the polynomial, one of {0, 1, 2} but the `loess` documentation warns to use caution with 0. This parameter is called λ in the paper.

```r
library("tidyverse")

iris %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = Sepal.Width,
      y = Sepal.Length
    )
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(
    method = "loess",
    method.args = list(span = 0.35, degree = 1)
  )
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>